# How to turn off google's dark mode?

Tags: firefox, google-search, dark-mode

I hate google's dark theme. Google turn on dark theme for me without any notification, but I can't find how to turn it off now (btw I use firefox)...

[image]

Comment: From a quick search, this appears to be an A/B test. Clearing all cookies may help.

Comment: thanks after I removed cookies the light theme returned!

Answer (score 1):

1. open google.com
2. click settings bottom right
3. dark theme off

you are welcome

Comment: thanks! It was the right answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on titlebar in Mozilla Firefox and select “Customize” option. You can also select the option using Firefox menu (hamburger menu).
2. It opens “Customize Firefox” window. At the bottom of the window, you get “Themes” drop-down box.
3. Click on the Themes menu and select “Light” theme.
   [image](https://media.askvg.com/articles/images7/Enable_Mozilla_Firefox_Light_Theme_Mode.png)

Comment: Doesn't help it's a problem with google not firefox

Comment: are you on windows? why don't you try chrome if you are on windows? or even edge? did you try using a different search engine(within firefox)?

Comment: Also, I like using a dark theme on firefox but do NOT what a dark theme on the google website. I believe it has something to do with google knowing what the system GTK theme is (which actually is a problem with firefox allowing google to know that information).